# Angular conditional routes

Tags: angular

i need to render a 'home' path, for this example either one component or the other depending on a conditional.
NOTE: It can't be HTML (ng if, or so)

I've 2 lazy modules, class and ideas. I need one of this modules (Components) to render depending on a condition

This is mi *home.routing*

```
const change:boolean = false

const routes: Routes = [
{ 
  path: '', 
  component: MainComponent ,
  children:[
    {
      path: '',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      redirectTo: '/home',
    },
    { 
      path: 'home', 
      loadChildren: () => {
        return change ? import('../../../pages/class/class.module').then(m => m.ClassModule) : import('../../../pages/ideas/ideas.module').then(m => m.IdeasModule) 
      },
      canLoad: [LoggedGuard] 
    },
  ]
}, 
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutingModule { }
```

This WORKS, the issue is that the variable changes, i need it to be dynamic. I need to inyect the redux store to evaluate it and change from true to false or other values, but obviously i dont have a class with a constructor to be able to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you could use a resolver and take a decision in it to navigate based on a condition.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of doing this would be to have a component that is loaded on `home` which then decides which component to show inside it.

So the `change` check can happen in there.

You can achieve dynamic loading as described [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) by doing the following

```html
  <div class="home-container">
    <ng-template homeSlot></ng-template>
  </div>
```

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[homeSlot]',
})
export class HomeSlotDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  change = false;
  @ViewChild(HomeSlotDirective, {static: true}) homeSlot!: HomeSlotDirective;
  interval: number|undefined;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadComponent();
    this.getAds();
  }

  loadComponent() {

    const viewContainerRef = this.homeSlot.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    if (this.change) {
      const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<ClassComponent>();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, im gonna try it out. By the way, do you know how to do the same but with a Lazy module? I mean, that it either loads a module or another on?